# Silverlight Error 0x17E0

Tags: c#, silverlight

Error 0x17E0.  Debugging resource strings are unavailable. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60129.0&File=mscorrc.dll&Key=0x17E0

Does anyone know what this error is?  I get it when trying to Print in a loop.

```
 at RealForms.ViewModel.FormNewViewModel.<Print>d__48.MoveNext()     at 
    RealForms.ViewModel.FormNewViewModel.Print(Object parameter)     at 
    RealForms.ViewModel.FormNewViewModel.<.ctor>b__6(Object param)     at 
    GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand`1.Execute(Object parameter)     at 
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ExecuteCommand()     at 
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()     at 
    System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()     at 
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)     
    at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)     at 
    MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 
    argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Comment: If you install silverlight for developers (not just the standard runtime) you will get a more detailed error. Link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b3deb194-ca86-4fb6-a716-b67c2604a139&displaylang=en

Comment: Yeah the issue is that it's a beta tester that gets the error and I can't install the developer runtime.  And I can't seem to get the error myself.  You know, the classic developer problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, that error indicates an `InvalidCastException`.